# phpunit partial mock laravel service with parameters in constructor

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

So I'm writing a unit test in phpunit with Laravel and I stumbled upon an annoying problem. I'm trying to mock a specific method in a Laravel service, but it creates a problem in another method because the partial mock doesn't call the original constructor. Here's part of my service class:

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Mail\ReservationMail;
use App\Models\Cart\Product;
use App\Models\EventArchiveTemporary;
use App\Models\EventArchiveTypes\ReservationEvictionType;
use App\Models\Trip\Reservation;
use App\Models\Trip\Ride;
use App\Models\Trip\Ride\Itinerary;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\User\Infraction;
use App\Models\User\ReservationCreditsLog;
use App\Models\User\StatusChange;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ReservationService extends BaseService
{
    private $userService;
    private $virtualAgentService;
    private $eventArchiveService;
    private $userWarningService;

    public function __construct(
        UserService $userService,
        VirtualAgentService $virtualAgentService,
        EventArchiveService $eventArchiveService,
        UserWarningService $userWarningService
    ) {
        $this->userService = $userService;
        $this->virtualAgentService = $virtualAgentService;
        $this->eventArchiveService = $eventArchiveService;
        $this->userWarningService = $userWarningService;
    }

    public function cancel(Reservation $reservation, $seatsToCancel)
    {
        $this->virtualAgentService->createUserScan($r->userId);
        $this->virtualAgentService->createUserScan($r->currentItinerary->driver->userId);
        $this->virtualAgentService->createRideScan($r->rideId);
    }

    public function sendReservationMail(User $user, $reservationSeats)
    {
        try {
            Mail::to($user)->send(new ReservationMail($user, $reservationSeats));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('An error occured while sending transaction email to user ['.$user->userId.']: '.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in my unit test, I have this thing:

```
class TransactorTest extends TestCase
{
    use ReserveSeats, CreditCardPayload;

    protected $userId = 36;
    protected $reservationUser = null;
    protected $withGetDistanceMock = false;
    protected $rideParam = null;

    protected function mockReservationService(Closure $closure, $partial = true, $bind = false)
    {
        $this->mockInstance(ReservationService::class, $closure, $partial, $bind);
    }

    protected function mockInstance($instance, Closure $closure, $partial = true, $bind = false)
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock($instance, function ($mock) use ($closure) {
            $closure($mock);
        });

        if ($partial) {
            $mock->makePartial(); //http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html#creating-partial-mocks
        }

        $this->instance($instance, $mock);

        if ($bind) {
            $this->app->bind($instance, function () use ($mock) {
                return $mock;
            });
        }
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->mockReservationService(function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('sendReservationMail');
        }, true, true);
    }

    public function testTotalWithCancellationOverMaxContribution()
    {
        $response = $this->createReservation();

        // This bit calls reservationService->cancel()
        
        $response = $this->requestAs(31, route('api.cancel-seats', ['id' => 250]), 'POST', ['seats' => 3]);
    }
```

The problem here is that because I'm partially mocking the `reservationService` object, the constructor is actually skipped and as such, the `virtualAgentService` variable is never initialized.

I've seen a few posts where you can give the constructor's parameter in your test...

It's just that in my case, those are actually what I like to call "magic parameters" that Laravel sets internally.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to circumvent this problem?

EDIT: To summarize, I'm actually trying to mock the `sendReservationMail` method because I don't want to actually send an email while doing a unit test. However, you'll notice that I'm calling an endpoint `api.cancel-seats` which in turns calls the `cancel` method located in the `reservationService`. So, because of the mock, the constructor is not called for this class and some dependencies aren't set because of it.

Comment: What are you trying to mock? A parameter on the constructor or a method on `ReservationService`? Could you explain just a bit more what you want to mock and why?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I added some clarifications... basically, the method I'm mocking is the `sendReservationMail` of the `ReservationService`. However, because of the partial mock, the `cancel` method doesn't work because some dependencies that are set in the constructor are not set... and because said dependencies are Laravel "magic" parameters, I don't know how to set them

Comment: You don't need to do this if you want to prevent an email to be sent (absolutely understandable), you have to mock the `Mail` call, you just have to do [`Mail::fake();`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#testing-mailable-sending) and that's it. One more thing, what you are trying to say when you say "Laravel magic parameters", you want to say "DI" or "Dependency Injection"

Comment: @matiaslauriti So basically, all I do is add `Mail::fake();` in my setup function and my tests won't send any email? And thanks for the bit of vocabulary, I forgot it was called Dependency Injection ;)

Comment: Yes, just add `Mail::fake();` and it will not send an email, so you do not need to mock any method to prevent the mail from being sent, just `Mail::fake();` and that's it!